# Injective holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

anyone can give me a hint, please.

Show that if $f \   \colon \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and injective, then for some $ c \in \mathbb{C}$  $f(\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\})= \mathbb{C} \setminus \{c\}$

Comment: What kind of singularity can $f$ have at $0?)

Comment: Poles or removable singularity.

Comment: And what happens if $f$ has a removable singularity at $0?$

Comment: f is continous at 0, but i don't understand why i must use Riemann mapping theorem.

Comment: @zhw. the question is, how does one handle the case of a pole?

Comment: @zhw. Didn't mean no offense, I was actually asking if you know how to tackle the pole case cause I'm stuck as well :P

Comment: @JustDroppedIn No problem. I gave a hint below. Hope it helps.

Comment: I changed my answer from a hint to a more complete solution. Ask if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well-know fact: If an analytic function $f$ has a zero of order $m$ at $z_0,$ then there is a deleted neighborhood of $z_0$ in which $f$ is $m$-to-$1.$ Corollary: If $g$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z_0,$ then there is a deleted neighborhood of $z_0$ in which $g$ is $m$-to-$1.$

To our problem: The injectivity of $f$ implies $f$ has a removable singularity or a pole at $0$ (Casorati-Weierstrass + open mapping theorem). I'll leave the rem0vable singularity case to you. Suppose, then, $f$ has a pole of order $m$ at $0.$  Then by the exercise, $m=1.$ Thus there is a constant $a\ne 0$ such that

$$f(z) = \frac{a}{z} + g(z),\,\, z\in \mathbb C\setminus \{0\},$$

where $g$ is entire. It follows that $f(1/z) = az +g(1/z).$ But note $f(1/z)$ is also injective on the same domain. Using the same reasoning as above, we see $g$ is a polynomial of degree $\le 1.$ It follows that there are constants $a,b,c$ such that

$$f(z) = \frac{a}{z} + b + cz.$$

Suppose both $a,c\ne 0.$ Then $f'(z) = -a/z^2 + c.$ Thus $f'$ has zeros in $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\},$ which implies $f$ is not injective there, contradiction. Therefore either $a=0$ or $c=0$ (but not both). From this the conclusion follows.